# Shorten Javascript Function

Tags: javascript

I wrote myself a function to turn a string into an abbreviation and it's currently fairly long  and it's case-sensitive.

I need a way shorten it so it works 100% of the time. Currently it screws up if one of the splitting words has a capital, if a word ends in a splitting word.

My splitting words are basically the words I'm removing (as most companies and such don't include them). They include:

- and
- of
- the
- for
- to

Also, the way I'm removing them is using split and join (`str.split('and ').join('')`) which to me doesn't seem like the easiest way.

Other than these issues, it works fine. Could anyone help me shrink the function and fix the issues? Thanks.

**Function:**

```
String.prototype.toAbbrev = function () {
    var s = [];
    var a = this.split('and ').join('').split('of ').join('').split('the').join('').split('for ').join('').split('to ').join('').split(' ');
    for (var i = 1; i < a.length + 1; i++) {
        s.push(a[i - 1].charAt(0).toUpperCase());
    }

    return s.join('.');
}
```

**Outputs on Tested Companies**

```
The National Aeronautics and Space Administration           ->    N.A.S.A
The National Roads and Motorists' Association               ->    N.R.M.A
Royal Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Animals      ->    R.S.P.C.A
```

Comment: How about using a regular expression replacement instead? You can use the `i` modifier to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: Could you show me an example? I've never used regex before.

@thefourtheye Thanks for the edit, forgot to do that before I posted.

Comment: Don't extend the string prototype for this. Extending native prototypes is generally very frowned upon in javascript. Just have a regular function - nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I know it's frowned upon. Just never understood why and it's never affected anything for me so I've had no reason not to.

Comment: At this point its worth doing just because it's **such** a strong convention people will get infuriated if they see this. The reason for the rule is the technique increases likely points of failure and zero benefit beyond a slightly different syntax. First it requires the use of the `this` parameter which most people do not really understand the rules of nor the (usually) simpler alternatives. Next, you can of course be clobbering other functions. Finally, its got all the same limitations as a global function, the fact that its namespaced to a string doesn't really change the scope mechanism

Comment: The biggest problem is if someone takes a dependency on your code, this creates methods on *their* objects. Say they were previously iterating of properties in "String" now they start getting a different value! A much more idiomatic approach is to use a module loader like require, almond, or browserfy and simply write functions. It makes sense - functions are the **only** thing in javascript to limit scope, everything else is window dressing much of which was added literally as a marketing gimik to make the language resemble Java

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Thanks for the reply. Only reason why I extend the prototypes is so I can use "string".toAbbrev() etc. instead of toAbbrev(str)... I just like it more that way & afaik, there is no other way to do this.

Comment: What is your expectation when a word is hyphenated `Smith-Jones` (for example)? Hard to give an answer that `works 100% of the time` when the specification is not fully defined.

Comment: @Spedwards I understand but again, I encourage you not to for the above reasons. An example of the badness this can cause - imagine you package your method up with bower or npm and put out version 1.0.0. People start using it! Then you upgrade to version 2. Now what if I'm using a project that has components that depend on version 1.0 and other components that depend on version 2.0. Suddenly THOSE components will stop working for me. It will look like a failure in those components and will not be searchable since this would only happen to people including the exact things I am in the same way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An even shorter one:

```
str.replace(/(and|of|the|for|to)( |$)/gi, "").replace(/(.).+?(\s|$)/g, "$1.");
```

To make sure it is capitalized you can do `.toUpperCase` at the end.

```
(.)     //selects the first character
.+      //matches the rest of the characters
  ?     //? indicates a lazy match
(\s|$)  //match a space or the end

$1.     //means "the first selected match plus a dot"
```

---

Let's make it into one Regex!

```
str.replace(/((and|of|the|for|to) )*(.).+?(\s|$)/ig, "$3.");
```

```
"Royal Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Animals"
    .replace(/((and|of|the|for|to) )*(.).+?(\s|$)/ig, "$3.");
//R.S.P.C.A

"Josie and the Pussycats"
    .replace(/((and|of|the|for|to) )*(.).+?(\s|$)/ig, "$3.");
//J.P.
```

This should, in theory, cover all legit names. For names with preposition(s) at the end, you can *technically* do this:

```
.replace(/((and|of|the|for|to) )*(.).+?(\s|$)((and|of|the|for|to) ?)*/ig, "$3.")
```

But this is clearly longer than the one with two `replace`s and this defeats its purpose.

Comment: derek, explain the regex for the latter part: /(.).+?(\s|$)/ , please

Comment: This doesn't account for if the excluded word is at the end of the string and has an extra period at the end ;)

Comment: @nderscore - It does now

Comment: @jamesemanon - `(.)` selects the first letter, `.+?` is the rest of the letters that we don't care, and `(\s|$)` means either a space or the end of the string.

Comment: This solution fails for certain strings. Example: "Department of Homeland Security" => "D.H."

Comment: Working, and slightly shorter version: `str.replace(/\b(and|of|the|for|to) ?/gi, "").replace(/(\w)[^ ]* ?/g, "$1.")` ;)

Comment: @nderscore - We need to go deeper `str.replace(/(and|of|the|for|to)? ?(.).+?(\s|$)/g, "$2.")`

Comment: For unexpected ending prepositions, you can add one more copy of the list to the end: `.replace(/(and|of|the|for|to)? ?(.).+?(\s|$)(and|of|the|for|to)? ?/g, "$2.")`

Comment: Hypothetically... "Josie and the Pussycats" => "J.t.P." (deeper version) and  "Foo and the of Bar" => "F.t.B." (unexpected ending prepositions version)

Comment: @nderscore - The code I posted in the comment is old. (I couldn't change it!) See the new code I posted in the answer.

Comment: It still doesn't work if the excluded word is at the end, which is a use case mentioned in the question. I don't think it can be safely done with a single replace.

Comment: @nderscore - Hmm... you are right. But is there really an organization with a preposition at the end? Just curious.

Comment: I am assuming that your answer is the final `replace`? http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/XZkpC/

Comment: I take back my previous comment. Single replace is possible with a function in the second parameter :P `str.replace(/[^ ]+ ?/g, function(x){ return /^(and|of|the|for|to) ?$/i.test(x)?'':x[0]+'.'; });`

Comment: @Xotic750 - Include `&` in the list of exclusions.

Comment: @nderscore - Using a function is like cheating.

Comment: Added, http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/C6KKK/ `'The Silica & Sand Society'` -> `T.S.S.S.`

Comment: You seem to be missing the `i` flag in your answer

Answer (score 12):

I think an approach like this might work better:

```
var toAbbrev = function(str){
    return str.replace(/\b(?:and|of|the|for|to)(?: |$)/gi,''). // remove all occurances of ignored words
               split(' ').                                     // split into words by spaces
               map(function(x){                          
                   return x.charAt(0).toUpperCase();           // change each word into its first letter capitalized
               }).
               join('.');                                      // join with periods
};
```

and here's a breakdown of the regular expression:

```
/
    \b                    // word boundary
    (?:and|of|the|for|to) // non-capturing group. matches and/of/the/for/to
    (?: |$)               // non-capturing group. matches space or end of string
/gi                       // flags: g = global (match all), i = case-insensitive
```

And here's an alternative method that has a less complicated regular expression:

```
var toAbbrev = function(str){
    return str.split(' '). // split into words
               filter(function(x){
                   return !/^(?:and|of|the|for|to)$/i.test(x); // filter out excluded words
               }).
               map(function(x){
                    return x.charAt(0).toUpperCase(); // convert to first letter, captialized
               }).
               join('.'); // join with periods
};
```

And regex breakdown:

```
/
    ^                     // start of string
    (?:and|of|the|for|to) // non-capturing group. matches and/of/the/for/to
    $                     // end of string
/i                        // flags: i = case-insensitive
```

Comment: Why not just `.replace(/(.).+?(\s|$)/g, "$1")`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 that would also be an acceptable way to get just the first letter, but it doesn't capitalize.

Comment: Yea but you can always capitalize the result and the end ;)

Comment: I think this is a much better attempt rather than using a pure regex, but would still require additions to the exclusion list in certain circumstances http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/RX37n/ I would also opt to use `x.charAt(0)` rather than `x[0]` as then you can just drop in the appropriate pollyfils for the ECMA5 and you won't have problems with environments that don't handle direct string indexing (most notably IE)

Comment: @Xotic750 I've updated my solution to use `charAt`. I try not to think about IE :P

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it using reduce. What you are doing is essentially a reduction of the string to abbreviation -

```
str.split(' ').reduce(function(preV, curV, index) {
    if(!/^(and|of|the|for|to)$/.test(curV.toLowerCase())) {
        return preV + curV.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + '.';
    }
    return preV;
}, '');
```

Comment: `reduce` would seem the way to go, but you could improve this by using the ECMA5 `indexOf` rather than your regex and have an exclusion list. And reversing `toUpperCase().charAt(0)` would have a little less work.

Comment: Performance isn't so much the issue, more avoiding this kind of thing is. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/AVXbg/

Comment: if you want to make it faster, swap str.match(rx) for rx.test(str) since you don't need to capture...

Comment: Now you have the problem `TypeError: Object the has no method 'test'` in certain circumstances. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/4C4jX/

Comment: yup, suspected that but was too lazy to check for compatibility. Changed back to match.

Comment: @Xotic750 `test` is a method of RegExp, not string. it should be `!/and|of|the|for|to/.test(curV.toLowerCase())` You should never get that error when using it properly.

Comment: Also, the RegExp in this solution needs `^` and `$`. Right now it will exclude words which contain and/of/the/for/to.

Comment: My words should have been in "all circumstances", I mearly created the fiddle to demonstrate the change that was made. :)

Comment: @nderscore - added starts with and ends with in regex

Answer (score 2):

why not try something like this instead?

```
var a=this.replace(/and |of |the |for |to /gi, '').split(' ');
```

Otherwise the rest seems fine

Answer (score 2):

Just do a string replace in the following manner :

```
var a = this.replace(/ and | of | the | for | to /gi, ' ').split(' ');
```

This would also resolve the issue of one of the splitting words being in the end of any main word.

For removing any splitting words in the beginning of the string, just do the following:

```
var pos = a.search(/and |of |the |for |to /i);
if (pos == 0)
   //remove that word
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution using ECMA5

Javascript

```
var toAbbrev = (function (ignore) {
    return function toAbbrev(myString) {
        return myString.split(/[^\w]/).reduce(function (acc, word) {
            if (word && ignore.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
                acc += word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + '.';
            }

            return acc;
        }, '');
    };
}(['and', 'of', 'the', 'for', 'to']));

console.log(toAbbrev('The Silica & Sand Society'));
console.log(toAbbrev('The National Aeronautics and Space Administration'));
console.log(toAbbrev('The National Roads and Motorists\' Association'));
console.log(toAbbrev('Royal Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Animals'));
```

Output

```
S.S.S.
N.A.S.A.
N.R.M.A.
R.S.P.C.A.
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/5yDav/)

You could probably improve the `split` regex (`/[^\w]/`) to handle further oddities. Or just split on whitespace `/\s/` and add to the exclusion list.